# Python Loop and save to NetCDF

Tags: python, loops, variables, netcdf, dimension

I am trying to create a new dimension and add current data to a new variable in a NetCDF file using python.

Lat/Lon are 2D arrays (variables).
id is a dimension.

```
from netCDF4 import Dataset

data = Dataset(netdata,'a')
lat = data.variables['lat'][:]
lon = data.variables['lon'][:]
id = data.dimensions['id']

ageme = []

age = 1

new_age = data.createVariable('age', np.float32)           

for i in range(0,len(id)):
    if lat[0,i] != -10.85000038:
        for eachstep in range(0,len(lat)):
            ageme = i, lat[eachstep, i], lon[eachstep,i], age
            new_age = ageme
            age = age + 1
data.close()
```

I think there is a small mistake around "new_age = ageme" this bit of code, but can't quite fix it!

Comment: Just for clarification, are you attempting to add the tuple `(i, lat[eachstep, i], lon[eachstep, i], age)` to the record `new_age` each time the inner loop runs?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Appending rather than  writing over.

Comment: Imo setting variable values should be in the form

    `new_age[index1] = age`
and you compute index from lat, lon

Comment: I agree. `new_age = ageme`  overwrites new_age every time thru the loop.

Comment: Can you be a bit clearer?